# print value of email field from a node

Tags: theming, entities, emails

I am using the below code to get the value of email. It works fine if the field type is "Text". But the field type used is "Email"

```
<?php
  $node=node_load(14);
  print $node->field_contact_email[$node->language][0]['value'];
?>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's an Email field, you need to query the array for `email` not `value`:

```
$node = node_load(14);
print $node->field_contact_email[$node->language][0]['email'];

// Outputs:
youremail@example.com
```

If you're intending on rendering the email address on a page, you should look into using [field_view_value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7), which will give you a string of HTML markup for a field value. The benefit of this, is that it will use the rendering function for what ever field type you supply it with.

```
$node = node_load(14);
$email = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_contact_email');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_contact_email', $email[0]);
print $output['#markup'];

// Outputs:
<a href="mailto:youremail@example.com">youremail@example.com</a>
```